# How can I setup a svn subdomain so I can checkin/out without using svn+ssh?

Tags: svn

I have a svn repository on my hosting account at ~/repository/. At the moment I have to create ssh keys to my server for users to checkin/out from the repository using a command like "svn+ssh://domain.com/project1/trunk". This is fine when there were 2 of us using the repository but now I have other people that might be doing work on the server that I cannot fully trust, hence I cannot give them ssh keys as then they will have access to my entire server.

I would like to setup access to my svn repository via a subdomain e.g. svn.domain.com, so that users can checkin/out from this location using a command like: "svn co http://svn.domain.com/project1/trunk" - without using ssh. Can this be done and how?

This should also help me solve my other issue of managing which users have access to which svn projects.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have access to the Apache configuration and activate the SVN Modules to be able to access the repos via http/https protocol. I'm not sure if you have this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to install Apache and run svn in a vhost (or a Location inside an existing vhost).

You can set Apache to use LDAP auth too. There are [plenty](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache_subversion_repository) of descriptions of setting all this up on the web -